# How to materialize a downstream asset independently in dagster using python API?

Tags: python, dagster

I have dagster==1.0.11 and I am trying to materialize a downstream_asset independently from its upstream_asset. I want to do it through the python API. Please consider the code below for reference.

```
# example.py
from dagster import asset, materialize, repository


@asset
def upstream_asset():
    return [1, 2, 3]


@asset
def downstream_asset(upstream_asset):
    return upstream_asset + [4]


@repository
def repo():
    return [upstream_asset, downstream_asset]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    materialize([downstream_asset])
```

When I call `python example.py`, it fails with:

> dagster._core.errors.DagsterInvalidDefinitionError: Input asset '["upstream_asset"]' for asset '["downstream_asset"]' is not produced by any of the provided asset ops and is not one of the provided sources

I would like to achieve the same behavior I get from the dagit UI.

In dagit (UI), if I select `downstream_asset` and click "Materialize selected", I'll get

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/pedro.viana/dev/nu/mock-model/dagster_home/storage/upstream_asset'
> (full exception in DETAILS section, below)

But, if I first select `upstream_asset`, click materialize (it succeeds), delete everything in the DAGSTER_HOME directory but the *storage/upstream* file (erasing all metadata, but effectively leaving the persisted result of upstream asset there) AND THEN launch dagit again, select downstream_asset and click "Materialize selected", it will succeed. It has no metadata about the `upstream_asset`, it simply checks if the file is where `upstream_asset`'s io_manager tells it should be. It is there and `downstream_asset`'s materialization succeeds.

How to achieve this behavior with the python API? I would like to call `materialize([downstream_asset])` and have it succeed IF it finds the upstream persisted result where it should be.

CONTEXT: I can have multiple instances of dagster running in multiple environments, but all with the same code version (and an s3_io_manager). So, if someone materializes an upstream_asset, it is available to all others running the downstream_asset, even if they do not know who and when the upstream was materialized.

**Details**

Full exception:

````
dagster._core.errors.DagsterExecutionLoadInputError: Error occurred while loading input "upstream_asset" of step "downstream_asset":
  File "/Users/pedro.viana/miniforge3/envs/dagtest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/execute_plan.py", line 224, in dagster_event_sequence_for_step
    for step_event in check.generator(step_events):
  File "/Users/pedro.viana/miniforge3/envs/dagtest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/execute_step.py", line 320, in core_dagster_event_sequence_for_step
    step_input.source.load_input_object(step_context, input_def)
  File "/Users/pedro.viana/miniforge3/envs/dagtest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/inputs.py", line 201, in load_input_object
    yield from _load_input_with_input_manager(loader, load_input_context)
  File "/Users/pedro.viana/miniforge3/envs/dagtest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/inputs.py", line 867, in _load_input_with_input_manager
    value = input_manager.load_input(context)
  File "/Users/pedro.viana/miniforge3/envs/dagtest/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/Users/pedro.viana/miniforge3/envs/dagtest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/utils.py", line 82, in solid_execution_error_boundary
    ) from e
The above exception was caused by the following exception:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/pedro.viana/dev/nu/mock-model/dagster_home/storage/upstream_asset'
  File "/Users/pedro.viana/miniforge3/envs/dagtest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/utils.py", line 47, in solid_execution_error_boundary
    yield
  File "/Users/pedro.viana/miniforge3/envs/dagtest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/inputs.py", line 867, in _load_input_with_input_manager
    value = input_manager.load_input(context)
  File "/Users/pedro.viana/miniforge3/envs/dagtest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dagster/_core/storage/fs_io_manager.py", line 181, in load_input
    with open(filepath, self.read_mode) as read_obj:
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out a way to do it using an experimental feature. I would still like to know if there is a recommended (not experimental) approach.

I can use `build_assets_job` to build a job for executing each asset. To build the downstream_job, I need to inform that upstream_asset is a source.

The resulting behavior is exactly the one I expected, just like running from the dagit UI.

Code below, running the script is enough to observe the behavior.

````
from dagster import asset
from dagster._core.definitions.assets_job import build_assets_job


@asset
def upstream_asset():
    return [1, 2, 3]


upstream_only = build_assets_job(
    name="upstream_only",
    assets=[upstream_asset],
)


@asset
def downstream_asset(upstream_asset):
    return upstream_asset + [4]


downstream_only = build_assets_job(
    name="downstream_only",
    assets=[downstream_asset],
    source_assets=[upstream_asset],
)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    import pathlib

    job_name = "downstream_only"

    path_to_module = pathlib.Path(__file__).resolve()

    command = os.system(f"dagster job execute -f {path_to_module} -a {job_name}")```
````

Answer (score 0):

As it looks like you've discovered, the issue here is that when you just invoke `materialize([downstream_asset])`, it doesn't have the reference it needs to load the upstream asset.

You should be able to address this by including `upstream_asset` as a `SourceAsset`.

You should be able to do:

```py
from dagster import asset, materialize, repository


@asset
def upstream_asset():
    return [1, 2, 3]


@asset
def downstream_asset(upstream_asset):
    return upstream_asset + [4]


@repository
def repo():
    return [upstream_asset, downstream_asset]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    materialize([downstream_asset, *upstream_asset.to_source_assets()])
```